# Initial load creates my tables in the sym_x tables schema

Tags: symmetricds

After setting up a master-master replication on top of PostgreSQL , I tried to perform an initial load using:

```
./symadmin -engine octopusdb reload-node 2
```

My setup is:
1. I created all sym_x tables in a separate schema (replication).
2. I created all my application tables in other schemas of their own.
3. I inserted into sym_trigger.source_schema_name the suitable schema name for each application table.

Still, the initial load seem to create the application tables under the 'replication' schema instead of in their own schemas.

Is there some parameter I am missing for the properties file, or the initial load command?

Comment: Do you have SYM_ROUTER.USE_SOURCE_CATALOG_SCHEMA set to 1?

Comment: I did not, so I updated the SYM_ROUTER.USE_SOURCE_CATALOG_SCHEMA to 1. Still I see in the log the message "The outgoing batch 2-134 failed: Could not find the target table 'base_profile'", so apparently it still looking for the table in the default schema.

Comment: So this is my current tables setup - is this not correct?  
In sym_router        : router_id=primary_2_common,target_schema_name=common,use_source_catalog_schema=1  
In sym_trigger_router: trigger_id=common.base_profile,router_id=primary_2_common  
In sym_trigger       :trigger_id=common.base_profile,source_schema_name=common,source_table_name=base_profile

Comment: Was batch 2-134 the batch that was originally failing?  if so, you need to mark it as ok and initiate a new load or change additional data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do I mark it as OK?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently for multi-schmea configuration,you need to create a separate record for each schema in sym_router (with a separate router_id, and appropriate target_schema_name), and for each table put a record in sym_trigger_router and sym_trigger with the appropriate router_id and schema name).

Also, once failed, I needed to remove everything from the tmp directory which is under the symmetric software, so the updates to sym tables will be recognized.